# Bus and DDR clock frequency on Android phones

Tags: android

Is there any way to check the bus and DDR memory clock frequency on any of the latest Android devices (ASUS Transformer Prime based on Tegra3, or Samsung Note based on Exynos 4212). Is there any way to set the bus frequency to a particular clock?

Comment: Any body can help answer this??